# How do i revert back an overridden 'Edit' Button on the record detail page?

Tags: custom-button

The standard 'Edit' Button on the detail page of a record has been overridden and routes to a VisualForce Page. I want another 'Edit' button (in addition to the existing one) that allows me to edit the record from the detail page itself. This is the standard 'Edit' functionality. How do I create another button for this?

Answer (score 4):

To revert the old button, you will want to go to `Setup` -> `Create` -> `Opportunity` -> `Buttons, Links, and Actions`. Then just make sure the override is turned off.

[image]

To add a new Button, you would follow the same path, but instead click `New Button or Link`.

[image]

Then just make sure your `Content Source` is `Visualforce Page`.

Comment: I don't want to revert the existing button. Instead I want to create another 'Edit' button which does the same thing.

Comment: My question answers that also.

Comment: @Aditi - Are you able to provide additional details as to why you wouldn't want to revert the existing button and create a custom button? That may help with the answers.

Comment: Eh? I never said anything about what you would or wouldn't want to do anything, just how. I don't understand how that's relevant?

Answer (score 0):

You could create another Edit button with onclick Javascript:

```
window.top.location = '/{$ObjectType.YourObject__c}/e?nooverride=1';
```